# Polymorphic Commenting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, polymorphic-associations

I'm currently developing an app which allows users to post from their own account, but if they're an administrator of a group or venue, they can also post as that entity.  I'm struggling converting the polymorphic association ideas from some of the other questions out there as generally they're all based around being able to comment *on* multiple things and not *from* multiple things.

I think my main issue is that I have my user's post form on the homepage, so it does not have an ID in the URL.

My post controller looks like this:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:create, :destroy]
  before_filter :load_postable

  def index

  end

  def new
    @post = Postabe.posts.new(post_params)
  end


  def create
    @post = @postable.posts.build(post_params)
    if @post.save
        flash[:success] = "Post created!"
        redirect_to root_url
    else
      @feed_items = []
        render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    redirect_to root_url
  end

  private

    def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:content)
    end

    def load_postable
      resource, id = request.path.split('/')[1, 2]
      resource_name = resource.singularize.classify
      if resource_name == "User"
        @postable = current_user
      else 
      @postable = resource_name.constantize.find(id)
      end
    end
end
```

and my _post_form.html.erb partial:

```
<%= form_for ([@postable, @postable.post.new]), remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Create a Post..." %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

my related routes:

```
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "omniauth_callbacks", :registrations => "registrations" }
  resources :users, :only => [:index] do
    member do
      get :favourite_users, :favourited_users
    end
    resources :posts
  end

  resources :venues do
      resources :posts
  end

  resources :groups do
      resources :posts
  end
```

Models as follows:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :postable, polymorphic: true
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
        has_many :posts, as: :postable, dependent: :destroy
end

class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base
        has_many :posts, as: :postable, dependent: :destroy
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
        has_many :posts, as: :postable, dependent: :destroy
end
```

It seems that I keep getting the error

> Couldn't find Post without an ID

but I don't know why it's looking for a Post ID if it's not been created yet.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You have `before_filter :load_postable` in your controller. By default it will run for all the actions in your controller, even when the id is not specified. The error is thrown by `@postable = resource_name.constantize.find(id)`, id is nil for index method.

Change this line to:

```
before_filter :load_postable, except: [:index]
```

Comment: I've tried this, and it makes no difference.  I've also tried deleting the index method and it still comes up with the same error.